# Regex capture group not including

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to create a capture group that only captures words that follow a colon such as `:tsearch` in the string below. Words that follow double colons should not be captured. The current regex is capturing `:tsearch`, `:`, and `:int`.

Do I need to use negative lookarounds? Not sure what to do.

Sample Strings:

```
":tsearch + some_word::int"
":trigram + some_word::date"
":dmetaphone + some_word::int"
"some_word::date + :tsearch"
"some_word::type + :dmetaphone"
"some_word::str + :a_word"
```

Current Regex:

```
/:(\w*)/
```

Regexr Link
https://regexr.com/3tk8t

Comment: Can you give more examples? Maybe just `^` to require the match begins at the beginning of the line?

Comment: It could be in the middle of the line, Sorry I'll add some additional examples.

Comment: Ok, so if you're trying to match `:tsearch`, from your examples, why not just have a regular expression of `:tsearch`? Please explain what distinguishes what you're trying to match from the rest

Comment: @Fralcon, why don't you use `:tsearch` as group capture for regex

Comment: Are you trying to capture first and last word?

Comment: first of all, changing * to + will not match the ':' string
if you don't want to match :int then either explicitly exclude it or ask that it doesn't end in an end of string, finally, I'm not sure why you're catching the word in a group if you want to catch ':search' ?

Though I tend agree your question is phrased unclearly  try ':\w+(?!$|\w)'

Comment: I've added more examples and clarified the requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Your example could be a great use case of **negative lookbehinds**, sadly in JavaScript they are not yet fully supported.

A possible solution could be "emulating" the negative lookbehind by reversing your string and then applying **negative lookaheads**.

Example:

```js
const string1 = ":trigram + some_word::date";

const reverseString = string => string.split('').reverse().join('');

const reversedString = reverseString(string1);

const matches = reversedString.match(/\w+:(?!:)/g).map(reverseString);

console.log(matches)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi Rodrigo, thanks for answering. I'm not sure why my questions lists that it is for javascript but I'm actually using ruby. Ruby has support for negative lookbehinds. EDIT: I think the javascript tag was autogenerated for this question, or I accidentally added it instead of ruby.